# 2 second interval before the auto save button in form

Tags: javascript, php

Can I Make a 2 second interval before the auto-save perform? this code shows my webpage with a single textbox in it, and it auto show my DTRSearch.php result. This code is working perfectly.

```
<div id="search">
<input type="text" placeholder="Scan" id="t1" name="t1" onkeyup="aa();" 
autofocus/></div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
function aa(){
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","DTRSearch.php?
nmnm="+document.getElementById("t1").value,false);
xmlhttp.send(null);
document.getElementById("searchdiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
document.getElementById("searchdiv").style.visibility='visible';
}
</script>
<div id="searchdiv" style="visibility:hidden; position:absolute">
</div>
```

DTRSearch.php it query a single row, this a simple form with a submit button, i want this form to perform an auto-save but before that it should show the form for 2 second

```
<form action="GetDTRSearch.php" method="get">
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo  $id_number;>" name="ID_Number" /><br />
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo  $fullname; ?>"name="Fullname" /><br />
        <p class="Ok"><input type="submit" value="Click Confirm" /></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the button to a simple button instead of an input type submit. Instead, add a click listener to the Submit button. The click listener should call a `setTimeout()` function to execute the form submission after 2 seconds.

```
<form id="theForm" action="DTRSearch.php" method="get">
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo  $id_number;>" name="ID_Number" /><br />
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo  $fullname; ?>"name="Fullname" /><br />
        <p class="Ok"><button id="submitButton" value="Click Confirm" /></p>
```

Then, assuming you have JQuery, add the following script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submitButton").click(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#theForm").submit();
        }, 2000);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: what about my GetDTRSearch.php how will it perform?

Comment: @BryanCarlo You're right. Sorry. I edited the answer. You should change the button to a simple button instead of input type="submit". Then put the action back. This way, the form does not automatically submit when the button is clicked, but instead triggers an event that waits for 2 seconds before submitting the form.

Comment: ThomasJames thanks for your help. but i dont want the button to be clicked. it should run on its own after showing the result in 2 second..

Comment: i was thinking if i could delay 2 seconds in may function, sense it automatically run my DTRSearch.php. using the same code.

Answer (score 0):

This is the sample html code you need to change.

```html
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" action="GetDTRSearch.php" method="get">
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo  $id_number;>" name="ID_Number" /><br />
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo  $fullname; ?>"name="Fullname" /><br />
        <p class="Ok"><input type="submit" value="Click Confirm" /></p>
</form>
```

Below code the form will be automatically post back to server after 2 seconds to the action method. 
make sure this code will be executed after the data will fetch from DTRSearch.php else it will send blank value to the server. You can use this on submit click or you can directly make function and call this after data is fetched.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
        document.forms["myForm"].submit();
    }, 2000);
```